# Unable to get access_token using Python from Dropbox auth api

Tags: python, authentication, oauth-2.0, dropbox, refresh-token

I tried alot and this is my **python** code to use manually generated access_token and incase its expired (as its lifetime is 4 hours only) so it wll use refresh token to refetch new access token, however, it keeps showing me this error:
`Error: 400 - {"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "code doesn't exist or has expired"}`

My complete code is:

```
import base64
import requests

app_key = '<APP KEY>'
app_secret = '<APP SECRET HERE>'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/callback'
access_code = 'ACCESS CODE GOES HERE'

def get_access_token(app_key, app_secret, access_code, redirect_uri):
    # Create headers
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(f"{app_key}:{app_secret}".encode()).decode(),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }

    # Create data for the POST request
    data = {
        'code': access_code,
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri': redirect_uri
    }

    # Make the POST request to get an access token
    response = requests.post('https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token', headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.status_code)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        response_data = response.json()
        access_token = response_data.get('access_token')
        refresh_token = response_data.get('refresh_token')
        if access_token:
            print("Access Token:", access_token)
            if refresh_token:
                print("Refresh Token:", refresh_token)
        else:
            print("No access token found in response.")
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")

get_access_token(app_key, app_secret, access_code, redirect_uri)
```

I tried multiple times generating generating new access token manually and using that but response never change

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're attempting to re-use an "authorization code", also sometimes called an "access code", in your `access_code` variable.

Dropbox authorization codes cannot be re-used however. Each Dropbox authorization code is only valid for a few minutes and can only be used once. The app should exchange the authorization code just once, immediately upon receiving it, to receive the access token and optionally a refresh token. A refresh token is only returned if "offline" access was requested.

Refresh tokens do not expire automatically and can be used repeatedly. You can find more information in the Dropbox [OAuth Guide](https://developers.dropbox.com/oauth-guide) and [authorization documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#authorization). There's a basic outline of processing this flow in [this blog post](https://dropbox.tech/developers/using-oauth-2-0-with-offline-access) which may serve as a useful example.